# Using amazon alexa echo in my application

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on a group project which entails generating many reports. We were thinking of using amazon echo. We would ask alexa to fetch the reports from a particular tine period or something like that.

We plan on doing so using Python.

It is possible using ASK(Alexa Skills Kit) SDK to achieve this goal ? Like, can alexa tap into our application and fetch all that we want. We do not want to use anything else other than Amazon echo.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible you need to create a custom skill for that, there are somethings that you might want to consider though,

- How long is the report: it will work fine if reports are small and giving you some brief overview or some numbers. you don't wanna listen to long report on that robotic voice.
- Name of reports: sometimes Alexa will not understand or misunderstood the name you're trying to say if it's complex one.
- meaning of tap into your application: In Alexa skill you can write custom logic just like you write for a software so If there's API to fetch reports then It can be done. The skill will call API and pass the data that you say to that skill, data like to date, from date etc.